# Why does sorting the smaller subarray first result in faster quicksort?

Tags: java, optimization, quicksort, tail-recursion

I've been experimenting with quicksort and learning how to test a programs speed. One thing doesn't make sense to me. I tried implementing a quicksort algorithm which uses tail recursion in Java. It usually runs faster. But then I learned that Java doesn't support tail call optimization. Why would it run faster then?

Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class QuicksortCompare
{
    private final static Random rand = new Random();
    private static final int MIN_LENGTH = 10;
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 1000;
    private static final int MIN_VAL = -1000;
    private static final int MAX_VAL = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /*long[] avgTimes = {0, 0};
        System.out.println("press enter to start");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        in.nextLine();*/
        for(;;)
        {
            int[] arr1 = generateRandomArray(MIN_LENGTH, MAX_LENGTH, MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL);
            int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length);
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            quicksortNormal(arr1, 0, arr1.length-1);
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = endTime-startTime;
            System.out.print("normal: "+duration+" ns\t");
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            quickSortTailRecurse(arr2, 0, arr2.length-1);
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            duration = endTime-startTime;
            System.out.println("special: "+duration+" ns\tlength: "+arr1.length);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(QuicksortCompare.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }    }


    public static int[] generateRandomArray(int minLength, int maxLength, int minVal, int maxVal)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[minLength+rand.nextInt((maxLength-minLength)+1)];
        populateArray(arr, minVal, maxVal);
        return arr;
    }

    public static void populateArray(int arr[], int min, int max)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i] = min+rand.nextInt((max-min)+1);
    }

    private static void quickSortTailRecurse(int[] arr, int lo, int hi){
        if(lo >= hi) return;

        int p = partition(arr, lo, hi);

        if((p - lo ) <= (hi-p)){
          quickSortTailRecurse(arr, lo, p);
          quickSortTailRecurse(arr, p+1, hi);
        }else {
          quickSortTailRecurse(arr, p+1, hi);
          quickSortTailRecurse(arr, lo, p);
        }
      }

    public static void quicksortNormal(int[] a, int p, int r)
    {
        if(p<r)
        {
            int q = partition(a,p,r);
            quicksortNormal(a,p,q);
            quicksortNormal(a,q+1,r);
        }
    }

    public static void quicksortSmallSide_old(int[] a, int p, int r)
    {
        while(p<r)
        {
            int q = partition(a,p,r);
            if(q-p < r-q)
            {
                quicksortSmallSide(a,p,q);//may supposed to be q-1
                p = q+1;
            }
            else
            {
                quicksortSmallSide(a,q+1,r);
                r = q-1;
            }
        }
    } 

    private static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r) {

        int x = a[p];
        int i = p-1 ;
        int j = r+1 ;

        while (true) {
            i++;
            while ( i< r && a[i] < x)
                i++;
            j--;
            while (j>p && a[j] > x)
                j--;

            if (i < j)
                swap(a, i, j);
            else
                return j;
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

}
```

Here is the profiler:

[image: screenshot]

Here is some output:

```
run:
normal: 42000 ns    special: 39000 ns   length: 35
normal: 1240000 ns  special: 1202000 ns length: 829
normal: 336000 ns   special: 37000 ns   length: 63
normal: 358000 ns   special: 179000 ns  length: 839
normal: 102000 ns   special: 62000 ns   length: 322
normal: 72000 ns    special: 61000 ns   length: 393
normal: 11000 ns    special: 10000 ns   length: 75
normal: 26000 ns    special: 27000 ns   length: 210
normal: 134000 ns   special: 58000 ns   length: 337
normal: 91000 ns    special: 94000 ns   length: 393
normal: 66000 ns    special: 70000 ns   length: 551
normal: 107000 ns   special: 115000 ns  length: 805
normal: 54000 ns    special: 57000 ns   length: 386
normal: 21000 ns    special: 24000 ns   length: 197
normal: 29000 ns    special: 37000 ns   length: 250
normal: 117000 ns   special: 122000 ns  length: 932
normal: 199000 ns   special: 205000 ns  length: 963
normal: 31000 ns    special: 147000 ns  length: 148
normal: 16000 ns    special: 16000 ns   length: 136
normal: 193000 ns   special: 191000 ns  length: 959
normal: 107000 ns   special: 199000 ns  length: 634
objc[712]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 15)
Profiler Agent: Established connection with the tool
Profiler Agent: Local accelerated session
normal: 674000 ns   special: 864000 ns  length: 450
normal: 24424000 ns special: 1798000 ns length: 186
normal: 3561000 ns  special: 2434000 ns length: 678
normal: 2112000 ns  special: 2148000 ns length: 908
normal: 1595000 ns  special: 1582000 ns length: 739
normal: 2179000 ns  special: 2248000 ns length: 936
normal: 1025000 ns  special: 997000 ns  length: 447
normal: 1185000 ns  special: 1161000 ns length: 574
normal: 1507000 ns  special: 2678000 ns length: 741
...
normal: 1554000 ns  special: 1534000 ns length: 656
normal: 366000 ns   special: 318000 ns  length: 152
normal: 138000 ns   special: 132000 ns  length: 67
normal: 1146000 ns  special: 1095000 ns length: 478
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 5 minutes 33 seconds)
```

Comment: TCO doesn't mean it'll run faster or slower; it means that (where such can be applied) the execution won't kill the stack with an overflow. 10 up to 1000 recursions levels is .. nothing. Try with 100000 items. Are the results still the same? If the recursive version fails to run then TCO likely isn't in play.

Comment: @user2864740 what you say makes sense but if tailcall optimization isn't happening how do you explain the faster speeds (since there's 1 more if statement it should run slightly slower)?

Comment: Also, since it's quick sort, *feed it degenerate data* (ie. sorted data when using the first element as the partition) so it reaches the worst-case and thus maximum recursion levels - if the data is randomized 100000 items is only ~17 recursive calls, which will hardly make a point.

Comment: The first step is to determine if TCO *is* (or is not) happening; again, I don't believe the test shown is a good indicator of such, and may actually result in very shallow recursive depths. Caching/pipelining (and whatever extra fiddling the JVM does to disrupt such) is a fickle beast.

Comment: How is `quickSortTailRecurse` different from `quickSortNormal`, don't they both have a non tail-recursive call followed by a tail-recursive one?

Comment: The timing results seem to vary too much to tell which is faster. Maybe try longer tests, or use a tool like caliper.

Comment: @fgb what is caliper? This is getting annoying, first people say use junit, then netbeans built in profiler, then visualvm. What's the best way to test the speed of a method?

Comment: (Whoops, a *max depth* of ~17 calls in the ideal/nominal case for 100000 items, but still - I don't think the presented code is a good test to argue the hypothesis.)

Comment: @fgb longer tests in what sense? I basically have the entire program in a `for(;;)` so I let it repeat for 5 minutes. Are you saying I should let it run for longer?

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't *guarantee* tail call optimization.

A JVM implementation may still do it, but Java code can't rely on it for correctness.

Comment: Does Hotspots on OS X do it?

Comment: I'm reading the code and both `quicksortNormal` and `quickSortTailRecurse` are equally tail recursive, the latter just tail recurses on the smallest part first. The effects you're seeing here are probably due to cache, not TCO.

Comment: oh thanks ya, I was following a guide but the example was buggy so there may not be tail recursion (I should've said that). So sorting the smaller array first has a better cache hit rate? How do you figure that?

Comment: You're running extremely small benchmarks with sleeps in between. The first benchmark will have more misses since the process just started scheduling again, while the second one will benefit from the first one being run first. For better accuracy, rewrite the tests to 1. run for about a second to warm up and 2. run for at least 5 seconds while timing them.

Comment: "The first benchmark will have more misses since the process just started scheduling again" I don't understand. I use two seperate arrays to try and avoid any caching. This doesn't work? How do you prevent it then? I left the entire programing running for about 5 minutes so why do you say "run at least 5 seconds while timing"? Thanks.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't just depend on the array, it depends on the Java runtime which is shared between the two. If you ran this program for five minutes, it spend about 299.7 seconds sleeping, and 0.3 seconds running your code.